# How to use suexec to execute commands as a different user in cgi

Tags: server, bash, apache2, cgi

I'm implementing a login page with cgi. I was able to retrieve the login and password correctly, yet I am unsure of how to change to that user.
I am using httpd apache.

After researching possible ways to do this, I've seen that suexec could be used to solve this issue but I'm a bit unclear on how to use it.

This is the cgi code I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<title>Form Example</title>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'

  echo "<form method=GET action=\"${SCRIPT}\">"\
       '<table nowrap>'\
          '<tr><td>Username</TD><TD><input type="text" name="val_x" size=12></td></tr>'\
          '<tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="val_y" size=12 value=""></td>'\
          '</tr></table>'


  echo '<br><input type="submit" value="Login">'\
       '</form>'

  # Make sure we have been invoked properly.

  if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" != "GET" ]; then
        echo "<hr>Script Error:"\
             "<br>Usage error, cannot complete request, REQUEST_METHOD!=GET."\
             "<br>Check your FORM declaration and be sure to use METHOD=\"GET\".<hr>"
        exit 1
  fi

  # If no search arguments, exit gracefully now.

  if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
        exit 0
  else
     # No looping this time, just extract the data you are looking for with sed:
     XX=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_x=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
     YY=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_y=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
     echo "val_x: " $XX
     echo '<br>'
     echo "val_y: " $YY
     su $XX -p $YY #I know this is not the best way to login but I'm using it for testing purposes 
     echo ""
     echo `whoami`
     echo `pwd`
  fi
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'

exit 0
```

Whenever I try the "whoami" always returns apache.

This is the link where I've got part of the code:
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/BashShellCgi.html